# Why do these two folds produce different results?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, higher-order-functions

```ml
# List.fold_left (-) 100 [1;2;3;4];;
- : int = 90
# List.fold_right (-) [1;2;3;4] 100;;
- : int = 98
```

What causes these two results to come out so differently and what is the process for that?

I tried running both with the same list and accumulator but was expecting them to get to the same result of 90 because aren't both folds ultimately subtracting 10 from 100?

Comment: Subtraction and division are not associative functions, which means `a - (b - c)` might be different from `(a - b) - c`, unlike e.g. addition where `(a + b) + c` is always equal to `a + (b + c)`. You can try using `(+)` instead of `(-)` in your example. By the way the choice between `fold_left` and `fold_right` is related to the function being applied being respectively *left-associative* or *right-associative*.

Answer (score 3):

It may be instructive to run `List.fold_right` with a smaller sample.

```
# List.fold_right (-) [1] 100;;
- : int = -99
```

So here's it's clear that `100` is being subtracted from `1` rather than the other way around.

Let's expand on that.

```
# List.fold_right (-) [1; 2] 100;;
- : int = 99
```

Huh. Well this makes sense if we consider:

```
# 1 - (2 - 100);;
- : int = 99
```

And then if we extrapolate the original can be considered equal to writing:

```
# 1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - 100)));;
- : int = 98
```

The documentation on [`List.fold_right`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfold_right) does specify this.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of `List.fold_left (-) 100 [1;2;3;4]` is:

```
(((100 - 1) - 2) - 3) - 4
```

But the meaning of `List.fold_right (-) [1;2;3;4] 100` is:

```
1 - (2 - (3 - (4 - 100)))
```

You can check that this is 98.

You can get the result you expected using flipped subtraction:

```
# List.fold_right (Fun.flip (-)) [1;2;3;4] 100;;
- : int = 90
```

The order of arguments to the fold functions is (I think) intended to suggest this difference. The arguments to `fold_left` suggest that you're subtracting the list from 100. The arguments to `fold_right` suggest that you're subtracting 100 from the list.

One way to look at it is that the difference is because subtraction isn't commutative.